# Find interval such that $f(x):\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\sqrt{a+\frac{b}x}$ is a contraction.

Tags: real-analysis

**Question:** Find interval $D\subset\mathbb{R}$ such that  $f|_D(x):\mathbb{R}^+\rightarrow\mathbb{R}:x\mapsto\sqrt{a+\frac{b}x}$ is a contraction, $0<b<a$.

**What I've done so far:**

I've shown that:

- by MVT $|f'_{max}|$ should be less than $1$,
- and since $f'$ is monotonically decreasing and $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}=0$ I only need to find the beginning of such an interval with $|f'(x_0)|<1$.

No idea why, but the actual difficulty for me is finding such $x_0$ because I have a function that depends on both $a$ and $b$ and if I try to simplify $a$ I can't separate it from $x$.

Comment: Now when I think about I could use the fact that $a<b$ and just evaulate it as if $a=b$... Wow that was so easy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My answer:
D has an upper bound $x_0=\sqrt a$ since $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}f(x)=\sqrt a$ and $f:D\rightarrow D$.

Now I can evaluate lower bound as:
$$b < 4x_1^4(a+\frac{b}{x_1})<4x_1^4(ax_1+a)<4x_1^3(a^{3/2}+a)$$
$$x^3_1 > \frac{b}{a^{3/2}+a} $$
$$x_1>\sqrt[3]\frac{b}{a^{3/2}+a}$$
$\implies D=\Big({\sqrt[3]\frac{b}{a^{3/2}+a},\sqrt a}\Big)$

Comment: it seems you have a typo

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably computed already, $|f'(x_0)|<1$ needs to hold. This leads to the inequality
$$\frac{b}{2x_0\sqrt{ax_0^2+bx_0}} < 1.$$
This leads to a polynomial inquality of degree 4:
$$b^2 < 4x_0^2(ax_0^2+bx_0),$$
which is probably quite annoying to solve exactly, but should not pose any problems numerically.

However, if you are looking for a ***contraction***, then there is another key property that you need to keep in mind, namely there must hold
$$f([x_0, \infty)) \subseteq [x_0, \infty)$$
Since $x_0 > 0$ and $f(x) \rightarrow \sqrt{a}$ for $x\rightarrow \infty$, this might fail...

Comment: It's a homework problem, there has to be a solution. Does any $D$ such that f is a contraction exist?

Comment: Oh, I get it, it probably places an upper bound on my $D$. Thank you.